# Create a centered GDPR banner

Tags: html, css

I am new with HTML and CSS and I am trying to create a simple  banner that contain a text and two buttons. The banner should looks to something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogD1o.png)
 This is my code:

```css
  .banner{
  position: absolute;
  width:90%;
  display:inline-block;
  bottom:50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
 left:0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 100;
  display:inline-block;
  }
  
    
  .banner more_info_btn {
   float:right;
  }
  
  .banner ok_btn {
    float:right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
<p> some text</p>
<div class="more_info_btn">more info</li>
<div class="ok_btn">ok</li>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to align the text and the buttons horizontally and vertically. Do you have an idea about the problem?

Comment: `<div class="ok_btn">ok</li>` You seem to be closing your tags with different tags, divs should close with a `</div>` In terms of layout, rather the floating, try looking into `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center` for a quick and easy center.

Comment: Also your css is not correct, you are not using `.` with class name in `.banner .ok_btn`

Answer (score 0):

If you want use position absolute parent has to be in container with position relative

```css
.banner{

  width:90%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
 margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  }
  .wrap-text{width:100%;}

    
  .more_info_btn {
   display:inline;
   margin:5px;
  }
  
  .ok_btn {
    padding:5px;
    display:inline 
  }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
 
<div class="wrap-text">
<p> textsome textsometext</p>
<div class="more_info_btn">more info</div>
<div class="ok_btn">ok</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but in you example the divs are also not centered vertically

Comment: Something like this ?